# Why won't my iPhone show the latest iOS 16 update (16.7.3) but does show iOS 17.2?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 13 running iOS 16.7.1, and when I go to Software Update, it shows iOS 17.2 as being available, but not 16.7.3, which is running on my older iPhone X. Shouldn't I have the options to update iOS 16 as well? The same situation occurs when I plug the phone in to my MacBook Pro and try to update from there.
[image: 13]

[image]

Comment: How did you get 16.7.1 on it? Last iOS for phones capable of running iOS 17 is 16.6.1 as far as I can see from https://ipsw.me/product/iPhone Usually, if your phone is capable of running the latest iOS, you will never get offered any further updates for the previous one.

Comment: @Tetsujin 16.7.1 simply came as an upgrade to 16.7. From https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT214034 you can see that 16.7.3 runs on iPhone 8 and later, and on my iPhone X I remember seeing the upgrade to 16.7.3 alongside a 17.x upgrade. When you say "usually," what do you mean? 16.7.3 was released on Dec 11, almost 3 months after iOS 17 was released, so that would not appear to make sense.

Comment: I'm on an SE2020 & can't go past 16.6.1 unless I move to iOS 17 [which I never do until about Feb the following year]. This matches the info at ipsw. iPhone X can't run iOS 17, btw, which is why it can have 16.7.3.

Comment: I'd love to see a screenshot of the 13 running 16.7.1, which would force me to rethink.

Comment: @Tetsujin Screenshots of both phones added

Comment: Thanks - we figured it out in the meantime - there was a crossover period which has now expired. Covered in Ezekiel's answer below.

Answer (score 0):

When a new major version of iOS is released, Apple offers it as an optional upgrade to people updating from the Settings app on their phone. The primary update shown is the minor version of the current OS.

People using iTunes or Finder will only be offered the latest version, which will be the new major version of iOS.

Here is a screenshot from [a user on Macrumours](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/apple-releases-ios-16-7-1-for-older-iphones-and-ipads.2407093/post-32619833) showing what this feature looks like when it is available:

[image: iOS 17 and iOS 16.7.1 side by side]

However, Apple does not offer this dual-track upgrade process indefinitely.  Apple does not allow these versions to be installed anymore and you must go to the latest version that is compatible after the dual-track upgrade process is withdrawn.

Comment: That's 16.6.1, the one I'm now stuck on. I want to see evidence of a phone with 16.7.1 on it, that's capable of iOS 17.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have updated my post with a screenshot from a user on Macrumours showing iOS 16.7.1 offered alongside iOS 17

Comment: OK, so there was a cross-over [which I was never offered, even though I wanted it] so anyway, the answer for the OP is that offer has expired. We need one answer that just states that. We don't need all this working up to it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have cleaned up my answer to just show the single screenshot - it's a pity that the Finder upgrade process doesn't surface this process

Comment: @Tetsujin I have a iP14Pro, which is capable of iOS17, but I have iOS16.7.2 on it.

Comment: @MarcWilson - I was totally unaware there was an offer on the phone that wasn't ever available on iTunes. I don't trust OTA updates, I've seen them screw up far too often over the years. I have a solid local backup on the Mac & run updates from there.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh, I totally agree.  I installed iOS 16.7.2 only because of the multiple WebKit vulns it patches.  I'm right now making a USB stick so I can install macOS 12.7.2 on my Mac(s) over 12.7.1.

Comment: But how can this truly be the case when 16.7.3 and 17.2 were both released just 4 days ago?

Comment: @irishwristwatch I'm not aware if 16.7.3 was ever offered alongside 17.X. 16.7.1 in the screenshot was from October 2023. For your iPhone X, since it can't have iOS 17 it was able to go to 16.7.3 but for your iPhone 13 it is only offered 17.2 now that the dual-upgrade path is no longer available.

Comment: @irishwristwatch The takeaway is that you can no longer upgrade to a version of iOS 16 for a device that is compatible with iOS 17. That was only possible for a period of time after iOS 17 was released.

Comment: @Ezekiel Which is annoying as I see no reason to bother with iOS17, but would like the security fixes from 16.7.3,

Comment: @Tetsujin And now there's a 16.7.4 released, today, which isn't available for anything later than an X.